# How can I provide data to a tempo template?

Tags: templates, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to combine auto-insert and tempo templates to fill new files with the right content automatically.

My goal is to make auto-insert call a tempo template, providing it with some data (a class' name for example).

Something like this :

```
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
'(define-auto-insert
     (cons "\\.\\([Hh]\\|hh\\|hpp\\)\\'" "My C / C++ header")
     (lambda()
         (tempo-template-c++-class))))
```

I'd like to provide the C++ class template the buffer's file name so it can expand nicely. Ideally, creating a file named 'foo.h' would expand the template with 'foo' as data, creating the 'foo' class.

I tried to play around with the "save list" as explained [in the Tempo Manual](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/tempo_5.html), but no luck so far.

Thanks for the help.

En passant, is there a better way than

```
(file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
```

to get a class name from the file's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-h f tempo-define-template RET` gives a list of template elements and their meaning:

```
A string: It is sent to the hooks in `tempo-insert-string-functions',
and the result is inserted.
...
Anything else: It is evaluated and the result is treated as an
element to be inserted.  One additional tag is useful for these
cases.  If an expression returns a list '(l foo bar), the elements
after `l' will be inserted according to the usual rules.  This makes
it possible to return several elements from one expression.
```

So just put `(file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))` in the template where you want the class name (and yes, I think this is indeed the best way to get a class name out of a file name).

Comment: It works indeed.

I wanted to keep the argument in case I'd like to generate a class that is not named like the buffer, but I guess this case doesn't happen frequently enough to worth the trouble.

Thank you.